# Excel count numbers, with taking day of today in account

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, date

I have an Excel sheet that looks like this:

[image]

In the column "Total" I have the total amount of minutes that need to be executed. 
In the days after the "Todo" column I have the number of minutes that have to be executed that day. Now I want to calculate the number of remaining minutes from TODAY in the "Todo" column.

For ex. on today (26/03/2020) I want to see 65 in the todo column (= 100 - 35). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `SUMIF` for this:

```
=B2-SUMIFS(D2:I2,$D$1:$I$1,"<"&TODAY())
```

this assumes:

total is `B2`

Your dates are in `$D$1:$I$1`

And the 'to do' minutes are in `D2:I2`

[image]

Comment: lol @ something blurry and missing the dutch Inhoud (content) vs inbound. +1 for making me laugh at the something blurry. :)

Comment: @LPChip glad I could make someone laugh today, I'm laughing at myself now for not spotting inbound was actually inhoud !

Comment: Haha yeah :) Good times, good times.